# Событие закрытия вкладки от показ предложений

Tags: jquery

```js
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit()
    {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
    }
```

пробывал такое но оно даже не сработало. 
КАк сделать что бы при закрытии страницы писалось что-то типа подождите  и открывался какой-то офер?(не алертом а сообщение в html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var stop = true;
$('html').mouseleave(function(e){
if (e.offsetY < 0 && stop == true) {

$('#stop-modal').addClass('active');
stop = false;
return stop;
}
});
Такой вариант мне подойдет. Пользователь выводит курсор за пределы страницы то всплывает нужное окно

Comment: А за такое решение пользователи вас побьют.

Comment: Ну это не мне нужно) тем более открывается небольшая форма которая не загораживает весь экран и пользователь просто уйдет если захочет

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit() {
  return confirm("You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?");
}
```

Comment: я этот код добавил выше и он не работает

Comment: @Vlad467 Нет, не добавили. Внимательность - важная черта программиста.

Comment: Во первых при обновлении  событие сбрасывается и при уходе с сайта уже не работает. 
а во вторых нужно больше чем alert. Нужно выводить в отдельных окнах товары . Как управлять DOM на это событие? ничего не происходит если в функцию записать

Comment: @Vlad467 Ага! Вы меняете показания? "событие сбрасывается и при уходе с сайта уже не работает" - это что значит?

Comment: захожу на страницу жму f5 даю подтверждение страница обновляется. После обновления закрываю вкладку ничего

Comment: @Vlad467 Сейчас браузеры блокируют такие штуки, ими в свое время много злоупотребляли всякие нехорошие сайты. Теперь можно вывести только дефолтное сообщение, не больше

Comment: Вообще никак нельзя управлять сайтом на событие закрытия вкладки?

Comment: @Vlad467 Чтобы этот код работал, нужно чтобы пользователь повзаимодействовал со страницей. В этом примере нажмите «Выполнить код», кликните в появившуюся пустоту (это пустая страница с примером), нажмите «Выполнить код» ещё раз — окошко выскочит.